# Как создать данную HTML-таблицу без ошибки валидации?

Tags: html, валидация

Есть простенькая табличка HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Таблицы</title>
    <style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-spacing: 10px;
    }
    table td, table th {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
        <caption>Таблица 5</caption>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">9</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Почему  [валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) выдаёт ошибку? Помогите разобраться.

```
Error: Table column 4 established by element td has no cells beginning in it.

From line 23, column 13; to line 24, column 28

<tr>↩ <td colspan="4">1</td>
```

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: ну раз у вас чисто табличная вёрстка то надо верстать без css и  в строгом синтаксисе , применяйте тот DOCTYPE при котором была табличная вёрстка , и очень мало а точнее ни одного сайта который пройдёт валидатор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <title>!DOCTYPE</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>

    <table border="1" width="90%" style="margin:auto; min-height:400px;">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="6"></td>
 </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="6"></td>
 </tr>
    </table>

 </body> 
</html>
```

вот это прошло валидацию w3.org , Doctype имеет очень большую роль

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Значит дело в Doctype. Просто другие похожие таблички спокойно проходили валидацию.